# Css validation do not work in asp net

Tags: asp.net, css, validation

i cant use css validation class inside asp.net controls but all other css design works correctly for example i just need to add class="validate[required]" to make a control validation in html but the same is not working for asp.net textbox controls i tried CssClass too didnt work.
please help, thanks in advance

`<asp:TextBox ID="txt_uname" runat="server" Height="25" CssClass="validate[required]"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: `validate[required]` is not even a proper class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
validate[required]
```

This is not a valid css class name.
This declaration means `validate` class will apply to those elements, which have `required` attribute.

Your css class

```
.validate[required]
{
  color:Red;
}
```

So try this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="validate" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: thanks a lot sachin, m noob in asp you just saved lots of hours of .net validations

Comment: what if css class is "validate[required,custom[email]]" ?

Comment: @miko1 I wonder where you did get requirements like that from.

Comment: @Mr Lister it's from a php project with jquery validation please help how can i make it work in asp 'required' one worked :)

Comment: If it's about jQuery, why did you tag your post with css? I'm not sure why you need to use those classes for styling inputs; use a different class for that. By the way, this is the same jQuery library that is mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9807042/1016716) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3896488/1016716), right?

Comment: sorry, yes it's same lib but the same code isn't working in asp, please provide some solution

Comment: I just did, in the comment above.

Comment: yes but it's not working can you give me asp tag as sachine did, sorry but i just cant get my head wrap around it